# Как привести строку к массиву? Не используя метод split

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть определенная строка слов, через запятую

```
let str = 'cat, dog, "home, happy", draw';
```

Вопрос, можно ли как то привести данную строку к массиву, так, что бы значение в кавычках было отдельным элементом массива:

```
["cat", "dog", ""home happy"", "draw"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var s = 'cat, dog, "home, happy", draw'
var a = s.match(/"[^"]*"|\w+/g)
console.log(a)
```

```js
var s = 'cat, собака, "home, happy", draw, 128, 1+2,3'
var a = s.match(/"[^"]*"|[^\s,]+/g)
console.log(a)
```

```js
var s = 'cat, собака, "home, happy", draw, 128, 1+2,3'
var a = s.match(/\s*"[^"]*"|((?!, ).)+/g).map(s => s.trim())
console.log(a)
```

Comment: а можно ли как то дополнить регулярное выражение что бы оно принимала и кирилицу?

Comment: @Кларк, дополнил, выбирай.

Comment: скажите можно как то дополнить выражение для одинарных кавычек тоже
пытался что типа /'[^"]*'|"[^']*"|[^\s,]+/g
но не работает

Comment: @Кларк, `/"[^"]*"|'[^']'|[^\s,]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте JSON.parse или метод from

Comment: Эм.. Это каким тут боком?